# Find where packages have been installed using rpm

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

CentOS 5.3

I have been installing some packages using

```
rpm -ivh package
```

However, I am just wondering what command I can use to find the path of where the packages are installed.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`rpm -ql package` should give you a list of all files installed for a given package.

Comment: rpm -qpl package.rpm will list the files the package contains before installing it.